# How to get Symfony to render a checkbox for a nullable field in an entity?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Let’s say I have a *nullable* datetime field in my entity:

```
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="due", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $due;

    public function getDue()
    {
        return $this->due;
    }

    public function setDue($due)
    {
        $this->due = $due;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And now in the `FooType.php` I define a form field for this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        // ...
        ->add('due', 'datetime')
        // ...
    ;
}
```

However, even though the field is nullable, the form field rendered will allow the user only to enter a date/time, but not to say that it should be `null`.

I would like to have either a radio button UI like this:

```
( ) No due date
( ) Due date:   [ control ]
```

or perhaps a checkbox:

```
[ ] Due date:   [ control ]
```

Ideally, if “no due date” is selected/the checkbox is unchecked, the control should be disabled.

Is it possible to do this elegantly in Symfony?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik theres no symfony provided solution

i would

```
$builder
    // ...
    ->add('due', 'hidden')
```

and in view you implement the logic with html and js

so two checkboxes on click on due-date you show a datetime input then

you just need to set the value (null || thedatetimeinputvalue)  to the hidden field before submit